# Different Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008

I want to install Active Directory on my windows server 2008 but I don't know what is the difference between the five Active Directory :

> - Certificate Services
> - Domain Services
> - Federation Services
> - Lightweight Directory Services
> - Rights Management Services

Can someone explain each point and the difference with the other points please ?

Thx.

Comment: Go to serverfault.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you probably know, these are very different services for very different purposes. What is your goal with this particular installation of Windows Server 2008? This information will probably help people steer you in the right path. The following is too long to out in a comment but I have attempted to pull the definitions from Microsoft for these five services as follows:

[Certificate Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), a service running on a Windows server operating system, receives requests for new digital certificates over transports such as RPC or HTTP. It checks each request against custom or site-specific policies, sets optional properties for a certificate to be issued, and issues the certificate. Certificate Services allows administrators to add elements to a certificate revocation list (CRL), and to publish signed CRLs on a regular basis.

[Domain Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707373%28v=vs.91%29.aspx) are Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) services that encapsulate the business logic of a WCF RIA Services application. A domain service exposes a set of related operations in the form of a service layer. When you define a domain service, you specify the data operations that are permitted through the domain service.

[Federation Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897402.aspx) is a standards-based service that allows the secure sharing of identity information between trusted business partners (known as a federation) across an extranet. When a user needs to access a Web application from one of its federation partners, the user's own organization is responsible for authenticating the user and providing identity information in the form of "claims" to the partner that hosts the Web application. The hosting partner uses its trust policy to map the incoming claims to claims that are understood by its Web application, which uses the claims to make authorization decisions.

[Lightweight Directory Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897400.aspx) is a Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP) directory service designed for use with directory-enabled applications. A directory-enabled application is one that uses a directory, as opposed to a database or flat file, for its data store.

[Active Directory Rights Management Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771234%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) (AD RMS) is an information protection technology that works with AD RMS-enabled applications to help safeguard digital information from unauthorized use. Content owners can define who can open, modify, print, forward, or take other actions with the information.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I install AD for management of users and their machines on the network.
This is a research project so I have to defend every choice I made.

This is why I ask it.

Comment: As you research more on this topic, I'd like to welcome you to edit the wikipedia article for [AD RMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory_Rights_Management_Services) as well. Thank you!